# RAILS error NET::HTTP.post_form “private method `methods' called for #<Net::HTTP url open=false>”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to send a require to other url using NET::HTTP by the method post_form and the rescue of backtrace returns the error:

> private method `methods' called for #<Net::HTTP
>   my_url open=false>
>   ["/home/duglas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:576:in`
>   start'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:507:in
>   `post_form'",
>   "/home/duglas/sgc/app/business/external/connection/export/hawk.rb:31:in`
>   export!'",
>   "/home/duglas/sgc/app/business/external/connection/export/hawk.rb:11:in
>   `export!'",
>   "/home/duglas/sgc/app/business/external/export/hawk/balance.rb:27:in`
>   send_balance!'",
>   "/home/duglas/sgc/app/business/external/export/hawk/balance.rb:7:in
>   `send_balance!'",
>   "/home/duglas/sgc/lib/tasks/send_balance_control.rake:5:in`block (3
>   levels) in '",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/activerecord-4.0.5/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in
>   `each'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/activerecord-4.0.5/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in`
>   each'", "/home/duglas/sgc/lib/tasks/send_balance_control.rake:4:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in`
>   call'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in
>   `block in execute'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in`
>   each'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in
>   `execute'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in
>   `invoke'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in`
>   invoke_task'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block (2 levels) in top_level'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`
>   each'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block in top_level'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in`
>   run_with_threads'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in
>   `top_level'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in`
>   block in run'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in`
>   run'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in
>   `<top (required)>'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/bin/rake:23:in`load'",
>   "/home/duglas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@sgc/bin/rake:23:in `'"]

```
module External
  module Connection
    module Export
      class Hawk
        require 'net/http'
        require 'uri'

        attr_accessor :hash

        def self.export!(*attr)
          new(*attr).export!
        end

        def initialize(options = {})
          self.hash = options.delete(:hash)
          @send_method = options.delete(:send_method)

          @uri = options.delete(:uri) { URI }
          @net_http = options.delete(:net_http) { Net::HTTP }
          @settings = options.delete(:settings) { ::Settings }
          @manager_repository = options.delete(:manager_repository) { ::Manager }
        end

        def export!
          begin
            manager = manager_repository.is_active.last
            self.hash[:token] = manager.token_importer

            url = uri.join manager.url_importer, send_method.to_s

            net_http.post_form(url, hash) if settings.connection_export
          rescue
            # TODO
          end
        end

        private

        attr_reader :settings, :send_method, :uri, :net_http, :manager_repository
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My rake:

```
namespace :send_balance_control do
  desc 'Send balance of actives associate lines'
  task(generate: :environment) do
    AssociateLine.voice_lines.active.each do |associate_line|
      External::Export::Hawk::Balance.send_balance!(associate_line)
    end
  end
end
```

### Edit

Balance

```
module External
  module Export
    module Hawk
      # Essa classe é responsável por enviar o novo saldo do associado para o HAWK.
      class Balance
        def self.send_balance!(*attr)
          new(*attr).send_balance!
        end

        # @params [AssociateLine] AssociateLine
        # associate_line [AssociateLine]: Associate Line que será enviado o saldo
        def initialize(associate_line, options = {})
          @associate_line = associate_line
          @export_balance = options.delete(:export_balance) { External::Connection::Export::Hawk }
          @calculate_repository = options.delete(:calculate_repository) { External::Export::Hawk::CalculateDataToSend }
        end

        def send_balance!
          # Método será refeito de acordo com o Brunno Henrique, Gerente de T.I.
          # Pegar a tarifa local pelo nome
          # 10:10 31/03/2014
          number = associate_line.number.to_s
          minutes_balance = calculate_repository.calculate_minutes_balance(associate_line).to_s
          cash_balance = calculate_repository.calculate_cash_balance(associate_line).to_s

          hash = { number: number, minutes_balance: minutes_balance, cash_balance: cash_balance }
          export_balance.export!(hash: hash, send_method: HawkMethod::DEFINE_BALANCE)
        end

        private

        attr_reader :associate_line, :export_balance, :calculate_repository
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Method send_balance! is private based on error description . Can you post External::Export::Hawk::Balance body ?

Comment: Thank you to answer. I added the code you ask me.

Comment: By the way, when I run the code of rake works perfectly. But when I run the rake don't works.

Answer (score 1):

You added attr_reader under private . Just remove private:

```
class Balance
.....
attr_reader :associate_line, :export_balance, :calculate_repository


class Hawk
....
attr_reader :settings, :send_method, :uri, :net_http, :manager_repository
```

I think that's a problem .

Comment: I edited answer . Need remove private in both class .

Comment: Same error again :/ 

when I run the code of rake works perfectly. But when I run the rake don't works